# CSV date Format issue

Tags: c#-3.0

When I am using date in a .csv file it creats a problem as like I have used 01/01/2011 it takes 1st jan 2011,that's right but when I use 01/10/2011 it takes it as 10th jan 2011. I mean to say it always takes in mm-dd-yyyy format. I have some gb of files are there to be converted into csv. When I am converting these files dates in the files are in dd-mm-yyyy format. And after conversion the value changes completely.Hence How to resolve this issue? Hope I made my requirement clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01/10/2011","dd/mm/yyyy",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

This specifies the format of the date in the string and should convert your dates correctly.